# CSS attribute :hover not working

Tags: hover

I am making a nav bar and using the :hover attribute.

My question is why does the opacity work when I hover over it but not the border bottom? I have tried it in Chrome, Firefox and Edge, and wrote a jsfiddle for you to look at.

Thanks

```
    <ul>
      <a href="#"><li>One</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Two</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Three</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Four</li></a>
    </ul>

    li:hover {
      border-bottom:1px soild red;
      opacity:.4;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pb4759jh68/yq3bwhjv/

Answer (score 0):

Simply a typo in "solid":

```
li:hover {
    border-bottom:1px solid red; //soild changed to `solid`
    opacity:.4;
}
```

Comment: @pb4759jh68 Also, I have the new high score on Arrow Game :)